# classOf[TextOutputFormat] requires parameters in Scala but works fine in Java without any parameters (TextOutputFormat.class)

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, mapreduce

When writting a simple Map Reduce program in Java, below line works fine.

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class)
```

but the same thing in Scala is expecting parameters.

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TextOutputFormat[<param>, <param>]])
```

Why does it behave differently ?
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Please first read the API documentation before asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `TextOutputFormat.class` is special syntax. In Scala, `classOf[...]` is simply a generic method call so far as syntax is concerned (of course, it's treated specially by the compiler). So the type parameter needs to be a type, and `TextOutputFormat` by itself is not a type (in Java it is, called a raw type, but it isn't something you should normally use; Scala doesn't support raw types). Write `classOf[TextOutputFormat[_, _]]`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Makes some things clear.
The Scala program still has some errors while running in Hadoop but then again this question was not for that program.
Thanks again. :)